# How to approach locality of all content/questions?

Tags: discussion

If I ask a question about primary schools, should I in the question say that I care about US context only.

then there might be same questions just with different location context.

Answer (score 1):

In your question about how [teachers are assigned](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4294/how-is-the-teacher-assigned-to-my-first-grade-child), I expanded the scope, rather than narrowed it, simply because there is no standard even within the U.S..

As Torben mentioned, in the U.S. schools are governed primarily by state and local laws, and federal government has very little to do with how the schools are run, aside from offering a variety of optional funding programs that establish guidelines schools must follow in order to receive the funding.

State and local governments determine everything from the curriculum to the lunch program, so your question about how teachers are assigned to classes couldn't be answered without knowing which school district you were interested in (this is one of those things that could vary even within a state).  Questions regarding a specific school district's administration are almost certainly "too localized" for our site.

If, however, you have other questions that are more broadly applicable, then yes, by all means indicate if you want US context only.  Just be aware that many aspects of the U.S. school system that aren't standardized, and "in the context of the U.S. school system" may not be specific enough for some questions.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes please.*

Some topics are universal, but education varies a lot between regions. If you believe that your question is not generic enough to be universal then please explicitly state that you're looking for answers about your specific region.

Regarding USA, I understand that laws even vary between states and districts. If you're unlucky, your question is so narrow that it might only apply to an extremely small region, so the post would have little value to the community as a whole. This might cause it to be closed as "too localized."